# render JSON data in view - play framework

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am new to play. I am using renderJSON to generate JSON data. How can I access this data in my view. I tried render("view",jsonobject). while I am trying to access this object in jquery script, not receiving any data here.

I tried with an ajax call. following methods are in my controller

```
public static void getJSONWords(){
 .......
 render(jsonObject);
}

public static void wordcloud(){
    render();
}
```

and my view "wordcloud.html" makes an ajax

```
       $.ajax({

    url: "/getJSONWords",
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function (data) {
             .......
            });
```

but I'm not getting any data for our ajax call. I tried with Firfox debugger, check log file ajax call is calling respective controller action. thanks for your help

Comment: What version of Play! are you using? Version 1.2.x or 2.0.x?

Comment: Usually I use renderJSon with ajax requests. In this case your data will be inside the first variable (usually called data) of the function of the $.get or $.post

Comment: @MarcoCalì I tried with an ajax call but I am not getting any data. can you please have a look. thanks.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint inside the post or get function you can inspect the local variable data

Comment: @MarcoCalì tried with debugging with firefox, for some reason not getting data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`renderJSON` returns the JSON to the browser directly, and does not get processed by a View.

If you want to access the jsonObject in your view, then you can do

```
render(jsonObject);
```

This will pass the json object to your view, and make it available as `jsonObject`. So, in your View, you could do something like.

```
<script>
   var data = ${jsonObject.raw()};
   $(document).ready(function() {
      // process your JSON once the rest of the document is rendered
   });
</script>
```

Note that I am using `raw()` to prevent special characters from being escaped.

UDPATE: Following your update with more info...it looks like your route is incorrect in your AJAX call. It should look like...

```
   $.ajax({

    url: "@{Application.getJSONWords}",
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function (data) {
             .......
            });
```

Comment: if you are doing an ajax call, then renderJSON is the right thing to do. Your routes are probably wrong though...See my update.

Comment: I tried like this $.ajax({
  url: "/getJSONWords",
  dataType : 'json',
  success: function (data) {
   var testData = data;}}); with renderJSON(jsonObject) in my controller but my ajax is failing. Thanks.

Comment: what is in your routes file? If nothing, then your route is incorrect. Put the route as I have suggested and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `#{jsAction /}` tag in your view as [documented here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/ajax) and [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/tags#jsaction). The tag is designed *to transparently get a method definition from the controller*. The document shows a lot of example for its usage so I guess this will help you in dealing with your problem.